# -bash: export: `Drive/Courses/Programming/nand2tetris/tools': not a valid identifier

Tags: terminal, bash

Every time I log in to the terminal, I get this error.

```
-bash: export: `Drive/Courses/Programming/nand2tetris/tools': not a valid identifier
-bash: export: `Drive/Courses/Programming/nand2tetris/tools': not a valid identifier
-bash: export: `Drive/Courses/Programming/nand2tetris/tools/:~/Users/nikhilagrawal/Google Drive/Courses/Programming/nand2tetris/tools/': not a valid identifier
-bash: export: `Drive/Courses/Programming/nand2tetris/tools/': not a valid identifier
```

Comment: There's a malformed `export` command in one of your shell startup files; either ~/.bashrc, ~/.bash_profile, ~/.bash_login, or ~/.profile. Check which of those files exist, and look through them for `export` commands. They should look like either `export somevariable` or `export somevariable=somevalue`. Spaces around the equal sign or a "$" on the variable on the left of the equal are common problems ("$" is fine in the string on the right of the equal). If you're not sure what the problem is, add the suspect command(s) to your question in code format (so it's readable).

Answer (score -1):

It sounds like either your `$PATH` has been changed.

Here is a link to reset your `$PATH`: https://superuser.com/questions/121870/how-do-i-reset-the-path-variable-on-mac-os-x